# What is the depth resolution/precision of Kinect 2?

Tags: kinect, resolution, depth

Does anyone performed testing of resolution and precision of depth data from Kinect 2 (developers preview version)?
There are many test of Kinect 360/for Windows, but I havent found any on Kinect 2.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of depth data is 512 x 424, and the official document says that it has 3x fidelity of the kinect v1.

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to know, if someone actually tried to measure/test the resolution and the precision of the data in the z axis (depth).